# Collection using join method on empty values

Tags: groovy

I've got a simple method that looks at the request parameters coming through from a form and displays the values in a string. This method is working just fine but when an empty value comes through from the form it shows something like this:

```
beef:mozzarella::milk
```

You can see that there's an extra ":" if the value was empty how do I remove that? For some reason checking if v.size > 0 isn't working. Any ideas?

```
final String[] products = ["meat", "cheese", "nuts", "dairy"]

String generateProducts() {
        return request.requestParameterMap.findAll { k, v -> products.contains(k) }
         .collect { k, v -> v.size() > 0 ? v[0] : ""
        }.join(":")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of `subMap`:

```
request.requestParameterMap
       .subMap(products)
       .findResults { k, v -> v ?: null }
       .join(':')
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates but doesn't that seem redundant? Is there a way to just update my v.size() check?

Comment: `request.requestParameterMap.findAll { k, v -> v && products.contains(k) }      .join(":")`. U never let me read the question as well. :P

Comment: @DelmonYoung you could do what dmahapatro superbly suggests... I quite like the readability of the former, but the succinctness of the latter

Comment: Even my former comment would not give the expected result I suppose. But this will `request.requestParameterMap.findAll { k, v -> v && k in products }.keySet().join(/:/)` :)

Comment: How about `products.findAll { request.requestParameterMap[it] }.join(':')` ;-)

Comment: Updated your version of answer. I had that one earlier but it wasn't any better earlier. `k, v -> v ? k : null` Return key if value is not null. :)

Comment: He wants the values in the output though, no?

Comment: @tim_yates your correct I want the values not the key. thanks!

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for the replies but your results seem to yield the keys not the values how would I retrieve the values?

Comment: @DelmonYoung you are expecting `beef:mozzarella:milk` as results. They are the keys I suspect since you are doing `products.contains(k)` instead of `products.contains(v)`. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe mozzarella is a cheese, and beef is a meat, hence they are the values of the accepted product types ;-) guess time will tell...

Comment: LOL, I missed it real bad. I need that "ale" I have not had for a long time. @DelmonYoung here is another version `products.collect { request.requestParameterMap[it] }.findAll().join(':')`

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll vote it up! Better than having it buried down here ;-)

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates I was doing something stupid now that I got some rest and looked at it your answer works thank you. Thanks dmahapatro as well for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to handle this would be:

```
products.collect { request.requestParameterMap[it] }.findAll().join(':')
```

Thanks to Tim Yates for the tap on my wrist to make me realize that I was becoming too generic about beef, mozzarella and milk when thinking of meat, cheese and dairy. ;-) (See comments on Tim's answer to notice my blatant ignorance)